# Creating matrix by reading data from Excel

Tags: python, excel, matrix

I'm trying to create a data matrix from an XML file using xlrd. Below is the XML data and my attempt:

[image]

```
import xlrd
file_loc="C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\test1.xlsx"
wkb=xlrd.open_workbook(file_loc)
sheet=wkb.sheet_by_index(0)

_maxtrix=[]
for col in range (sheet.ncols):
    for row in range (sheet.nrows):
        _matrix.append(sheet.cell_value(row,col))
print _matrix
```

My output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

Desired output:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[2,3,4,5],
[3,4,5,6],
[4,5,6,7]]
```

Any ideas on how to get the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible way is to use pandas.

You can read your csv with the method `read_excel` and then convert it to a matrix.

Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("something.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
a = df.as_matrix()
```

Comment: `as_matrix()` is obsolete. Use `to_numpy()` instead. See the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy).

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to one list, so you obtain 1 list.

You will have to add lists to `_matrix`. Something like that should do the trick:

```
_matrix=[]
for row in range (sheet.nrows):
    _row = []
    for col in range (sheet.ncols):
        _row.append(sheet.cell_value(row,col))
    _matrix.append(_row)
```

If you want `int` instead of `float`, convert the values with

```
        _col.append(int(sheet.cell_value(row,col)))
```

Comment: how do I read a particular column? for example 'column c' to get the list; `[3,4,5,6]`

Comment: I just found out it your solution doesn't work as expected as the matrix has to be transposed.

Comment: @user2274879 it's possible. I had just copy/paste your code to modify it without checking (can't import xrld right now). I have edited the code. It should work as intended now.

Comment: now you got it. Many thanks for your efforts. Please can you address how to read a selected column?

Comment: @user2274879 `[row[2] for row in _matrix]` should work